# saving application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

how to save application state and restore it after reboot in .NET 3.5 (c#)?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. The *best* way depends on your requirements. Your question sounds like you *don't* need a centralised / concurrent / redundant / secured / scalable database.

To just store some configuration / data I'd suggest using **XML serialization**. There are many tutorials for this basic topic, like:

http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of state you're talking about. If it's just a few values, you could just write them to the app.config or some other XML or text file. If you want to store the actual objects then you might want to look at serialization.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx) article seems like a good place to get some basic info about that.